# Will this Instant Repeater design work reliably?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm currently looking into the mechanism of redstone in minecraft. For one circuit, I need an instant repeater, and reading Minecraft wiki, the smallest one so far is the 4x5x3 instant repeater by sethbling.

Experimenting a bit, I found the attached circuit to repeat instantly as well (both noteboxes activate at the same time, at least more synced compared to a one tick delay introduced by a repeater).

[image: My Instant Repeater]

Is there any fault with this circuit? I am suprised that I couldn't find this solution googling for instant repeaters as its even more compact (3x3x2).

Comment: In the future, may I recommend using white wool or iron blocks to make seeing the redstone easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there seems to be a smaller setup (1x3x2) [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEa27HPQwLA), but the wiki doesn't seem  to reflect that. I see nothing wrong with this setup, congrats on coming up with such a compact design!

Edit: you're design also has the advantage of only using one piston, because nothing lags minecraft like a bunch of pistons.

Comment: I think I saw a link to this video on the wiki, it said however, that this setup has a pulse effect.

Comment: Yea, apparently it adds an extra half tick before shutoff no matter how many you chain together

Answer (score 1):

This design will produce a short redstone pulse of half a tick which if u are building a piston powered machine then it may break the pistons. U have built halve a instant bud switch. This might cause a problem... If you turn the piston so it is the way the wire is pointing you will not encounter this problem... Look at sethblings "Redstone lessons with a mojangster"  I believe part 3. That is the smallest that is possible.